# How do I combine pills, collapse and tabs in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create some pills, which when clicked will show and switch between some content.

This works fine.

I would like to hide the content as well, when clicking the active pill again. This I cannot get to work.

This is my current code, which you can try at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9phcsmwa/1/

When you click one of the pills it will display the content, and when you click another pill it will switch between the content like tabs. But how do I hide the content, when clicking on the active pill?

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div data-parent="#accordion" href="">
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-toggle="collapse" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Pill1" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">Pill1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Pill2" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">Pill2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Pill3" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">Pill2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Pill1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Pill 1</h3>
            <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Pill2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Pill 2</h3>
            <p>Some content for Pill 2.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Pill3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Pill 3</h3>
            <p>Some content for Pill 3.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code you pasted is not in the jsfiddle you linked. Have you saved it ?

Comment: sorry about that. It should work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need javascript for this, you just need to change all of your references to tabs to collapse. Tabs are meant for one to always be shown, however, collapse is made to ... collapse!

[Here is you JSFiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/9phcsmwa/3/)

Changes include:

- All of your `data-toggle="tab"` are now `data-toggle="collapse"`.
- All of your `class="tab-pane fade"` are now `class="collapse fade"`.
- Wrapped your three tab contents in a panel. This is due to a bug with data-parent in Bootstrap. Details can be [found here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966).
- Removed `data-parent="#accordion"` and then added `data-parent="#collapse"` to all three of your Pills.

Comment: @ThomasD No problem, glad to help out!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#accordion [data-toggle="tab"]').click(function() {
       var $targetTabContent = $($(this).attr('href'));
       if ($targetTabContent.hasClass('active')) {
          $targetTabContent.removeClass('active');
       }    
    });
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9phcsmwa/2/)

Comment: I just realised that when I click Pill1 then it will show the content, and if I click Pill1 again, then it will hide the content. So far so good. But if I then click Pill1 again it doesn't show the content again. Is it possible to make it toggle the content? thanks